# Add post to cart

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying in Wordpress to create a simple "add to cart" function, which in fact more are going to act as a list of posts that the visitor have saved. I want to do it by ajax using admin-ajax.php and action.

My javascript looks like this and does what I want it to. It's passing the id of a post to an action. My weak point is the Php here. What I want to do is to get the posts by the ID passed and then list them on another page using a regular foreaach loop. How would I do that? By some session?

```
$('button.js-add-to-cart').on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const el = $(e.currentTarget);
  const id = el.data('id');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
      action: 'add_to_cart',
      id: id
    },
    success: function(output) {
      el.find('.label').hide();
      el.find('.response').text(output);
      el.addClass('bg-branding-success pointer-events-none');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      //var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
    }
  });
});
```

Below is my PHP which I need help with. (functions.php)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', array($this, 'mediabank_add_to_cart'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', array($this, 'mediabank_add_to_cart'));

function mediabank_add_to_cart() {
  if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone having an idea?

Comment: Can I somehow add the IDs to a session variable and loop through?

Comment: Nailed it aight!